# Create an alias with relative path

Tags: alias, csh

I have several directories containing abc/setup.csh. I don't want to type source abc/setup.csh every often. I tried making an alias but they did not work

```
alias sose='abc/setup.csh'
```

or

```
alias sose='$PWD/abc/setup.csh'
```

or

```
alias sose='./abc/setup.csh'
```

I got the following error:

```
readlink: missing operand
Try `readlink --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
```

I cannot use the absolute path as there are several such directories with the same hierarchy. My shell is csh. Please help.

Edit: Following is the content of my reduced setup.csh

```
#!/bin/csh

set called=($_)

if ( "$called" != "" ) then
    set script_fn=`readlink -f $called[2]`
else
    set script_fn=`readlink -f $0`
endif

set rootdir=`dirname $script_fn`
setenv ABCD $rootdir/..
setenv SCRIPTS $rootdir

set -f path=("$ABCD/kkk/bin" $path:q)
set -f path=("$SCRIPTS/precheckin_regression" $path:q)
set -f path=("$SCRIPTS/scripts" $path:q)
set -f path=("$SCRIPTS/script_gen" $path:q)
```

-Thanks

Comment: I don't see how the alias definition is producing these error messages. (I did have to use `csh` for 5 years, so I'm not just winging it here ;-) ). Please include the smallest sample subset of `setup.csh` that sproduces your errors. Again, if I'm guessing correctly about your end goal, problems like these with any implementation of alias x=...` is why you really need to switch to `bash` or zsh` (or even `ksh`), as those langages all support `functions` that can take arguements without any hacking required. Good luck.

Comment: That's the wrong syntax for the `alias` command in csh.  Try `alias sose "source abc/setup.sh"`.

Comment: @ottomeister My syntax works for other aliases so I guess both the syntax are correct. Anyway I tried your syntax too and it gives the same error

Comment: Aside from the syntax (maybe you have a `csh` that has been taught to handle an `=` in an `alias` command) the difference is that your aliases execute the script as a subprocess. They do not source it into the existing shell. Also, as @shellter said, those `readlink` and `dirname` errors are coming from the statements inside the `abc/setup.csh` file.  You haven't shown us what's inside that script so we can't help you with that part of the problem.

Comment: @ottomeister Thanks for your response. My apologies for delayed response. I have updated the question with a reduced setup.csh. Could you please have a look?